# Migrate SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Web

Tags: sql-server-2008, migration

I need to upgrade to a least expensive SQL Server variant which is SQL Server 2008 R2 Web. I'm currently using SQL Server 2008 R2 Express 64bit. Specs. say there's not direct upgrade path supported from SQL Server 2008 R2 Express to SQL Server 2008 R2 Web.

Can anyone here please guide me with strategies and options to migrate my databases from SQL Server Express to SQL Server web ?

Answer (score 1):

Back your databases up, remove express, install web, restore the DBs.

**but**

if permissions matter - you need first to save current and then do the move, and after it - restore login-users pairs in your DBs with its permissions

**or** you may perform simple detach/attach strategy, but the permissions issue is still in.